# Calling LineUp etc. Methods of a ScrollViewer Usercontrol in MVVM pattern

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, scrollviewer

I have a WPF 3.5 MVVVM application which has a TextBlock in a ScrollViewer. I want to be able to call the LineUp/LineDown method of the control whenever there is a newline in the text block.

How do I implment this without violating any MVVM principles?

Thanks in advance,

Satya

```
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" CornerRadius="1" Margin="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <ScrollViewer Name="Scroll" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MinWidth="120" Height="80" 
                              CanContentScroll="True" 
                              >
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Padding="5" FontSize="10" Text="{Binding Path=GetScrollLogMessage}" DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
```

Comment: To more generic : How is any method of any control handled in MVVM? In case of button, one could handle using 'Command'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raise an event in your view model, and handle the event in the view's code-behind.

Comment: Isnt handling the event in view's code behind a violation of MVVM? Could you please put some sample code?

Comment: It's not a violation of MVVM at all.  The view model doesn't know anything about the view, it just knows that it's raising an event.  You can still instantiate and test the view model without instantiating the view, which is the acid test of how well you've handled the separation of concerns between the two.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I was looking at a similar question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705250/calling-a-method-of-a-usercontrol-in-mvvm . Is this something different? Sorry if I sound stupid.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute ScrollViewer.scrollToBottom() when textblock.textChanged event fires.

Comment: But where do I execute the method? In the view's code behind? Doenst MVVM mean no code-behind?

Comment: MVVM means separation of concerns.  Keeping the text block scrolled into view is a layout-level concern.  It's similar to alignment:  you might implement an alignment property in the view model and then bind it to a `HorizontalAlignment` property in the view; the view model says "I want this alignment," but the view actually manages the alignment state of the control when the property changes.