# Calling a method of a UserControl somewhere in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I have the following scenario:

1. I have a user control, let's say `UserControl.xaml`
2. In the code behind of this control I have the method `DoSomething()`
3. I have viewmodel for this control `UserControlViewModel.cs`

I need to call usercontrol's `DoSomething()` method somewhere. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705250/calling-a-method-of-a-usercontrol-in-mvvm?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I really had to do this, then using the DataContextChanged event may help.
Here's a solution with hopefully minimal coupling between the view and the view-model.

```
public partial class MainWindow : IMainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.DataContextChanged += this.MainWindowDataContextChanged;

        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainWindowDataContextChanged(object sender, 
                     DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = this.DataContext as IMainWindowViewModel;
        if (vm != null)
        {
            vm.View = this;
        }
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Do something in the view");
    }
}

public interface IMainWindow
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class MainWindowViewModel : IMainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this.DoSomethingCommand = new RelayCommand(this.DoSomething);
    }

    public ICommand DoSomethingCommand { get; set; }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Do something in the view model");

        var view = this.View;
        if (view != null)
        {
            view.DoSomething();
        }
    }

    public IMainWindow View { get; set; }
}

public interface IMainWindowViewModel
{
    IMainWindow View { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should be [using an MVVM framework if you're doing MVVM](http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/UsingTheMVVMPatternRequiresAFramework.aspx). A framework would provide a mechanism from which you can invoke a verb (method) on your view model from your view. [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) for example provides [Actions](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions&referringTitle=Documentation).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though your application is incorrectly structured.

What does

```
DoSomething()
```

do, that isn't reacting to a change in a bound property of the ViewModel?

If you really need to trigger something in the code behind of the View from the ViewModel, use a messaging handler such as the one in the [Galasoft MVVMLight](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/) framework.